# R: aggregate multiple large XML files and put them into one data frame

Tags: r, xml, csv

I'm very new with R and I try to combine and parse several XML elements. I have imported a CSV with one column containing 178 XML addresses.
I want to "take" those XML addresses, convert them in one large XML file and parse it in a data frame. Eventually I want to export this dataframe as a CSV.

I have installed XML and XML2 packages. Then I have followed a tutorial and tried to work on a single XML address (http://ec.europa.eu/europeaid/files/iati/XI-IATI-EC_DEVCO_C_AG.xml) with xmlTreeParse function.
I also have imported the CSV with the 178 addresses.
But I don't know how to get a data frame from what I have got here.

```
# Install and load the necessary packages
library(XML)
library(xml2)

# Save the URL of the xml file in a variable
 xml.url <- "http://ec.europa.eu/europeaid/files/iati/XI-IATI-EC_DEVCO_C_AG.xml"

# Use the xmlTreePares-function to parse xml file directly from the web
 xmlfile <- xmlTreeParse(xml.url)

# The xml file is now saved as an object you can easily work with in R
class(xmlfile)

# Use the xmlRoot-function to access the top node
xmltop = xmlRoot(xmlfile)

# Have a look at the XML-code of the first subnodes
print(xmltop)[1:2]

# To extract the XML-values from the document, use xmlSApply
devcoafgh <- xmlSApply(xmltop, function(x) xmlSApply(x, xmlValue))

 # Finally, get the data in a data-frame and have a look at the first rows and columns (PROBLEM)
 devcoafgh_df <- data.frame(t(devcoafgh),row.names=NULL)
 devcoafgh_df[1:5,1:4]

# Just 3 tests
print(devcoafgh)
print(xmlfile)

 write.csv(devcoafgh_df, file = "afghdata.csv")

# Tests done
# Import data containing all XML addresses
 xmladdresses <- read.csv("xml_addresses.csv")

# Create a variable with just the right column
xmlurls <- xmladdresses[c(5)]

# Save all URL's contained in this variable in new variables (178 in total)
xml.list <- (xmlurls)
```

In the end, I'm expecting to have one large data frame compiling the 178 XML files I would be able to parse and export.

Comment: Not sure to understand but I have exported one XML URL as a CSV with OpenRefine. Now I want to use R to avoid exporting the 178 XML URL's manually and group them in a single dataset

Comment: My desired output is a dataframe with the 178 XML addresses.

Comment: OpenRefine is a software that helped me to make a CSV out of one of the XML addresses. But it would be too long to do it 178 times. So I could do it simply wit R

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but for your example with one XML-File, this creates one `tibble` with all the information (and if any is missing it will just fill in `NA`)

```
library(tidyverse)
devcoafgh_ldf <- lapply(devcoafgh,function(lst){
  tb <-enframe(unlist(lst))
  tb$name <- make.names(tb$name,unique=T)
  return(tb)
  })

devcoafgh_df <- devcoafgh_ldf %>% reduce(left_join,by="name") %>% gather(variable,value,-name) %>% spread(name, value)
```

Comment: Best result so far, thank you!
Not yet what I am looking for but I'll keep trying. You might have give me a good spark